Azure AD B2C Registration claims mapping
So, I have made a sign up custom policy flow which captures the query url params into the input fields of the custom policy.
EDIT 1
Upon further investigations, I have captured the token and all the information is passed correctly in it.
Now, what I want to do, is to pass the claims in the input fields into the Contact (default one) table in Dataverse. I am doing this through the identity provider configuration of Azure AD B2C -> Advanced Settings -> Registration claims mapping. What I want to pass is the given name, surname, email, extension_middleName, extension_mobilePhone, jobTitle and extension_organisationName. These are the Azure AD B2C claims. Btw, if it helps, the information is saved on the User in the Azure AD B2C environment.
By default, it seems that Dataverse receives only the given name claim and e-mail which are registered in the Contact table. I am also using Power Pages if of any help and after signing up I redirect the user to the profile page (the default one of Power Pages).
The contact table column names (Contact) are as follows (will add both schema and logical name since I am not sure which one to use since none seems to work for me):

Logical names: firstname, lastname, emailaddress1, middlename, mobilephone, jobtitle, adx_organizationname
Schema names: FirstName, LastName, EMailAddress1, MiddleName, MobilePhone, JobTitle, Adx_OrganizationName

I have tried the following in the Registration Claim Mapping (both with logical and schema name):
firstname=given_name,lastname=surname,emailaddress1=email,middlenameextension_middleName,mobilephone=extension_mobilePhone,jobtitle=job_title,adx_organizationname=extension_organisationName
Raw claims
  "claims_supported": [
    "name",
    "given_name",
    "family_name",
    "email",
    "middleName",
    "mobile_phone",
    "job_title",
    "organisationName",
    "sub",
    "tid",
    "iss",
    "iat",
    "exp",
    "aud",
    "acr",
    "nonce",
    "auth_time"
  ]

Here is my custom policy code (also this is made for local accounts):
TrustFrameworkBase.xml(Technical Profile for signing up)
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
          <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
            <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" DefaultValue="{OAuth-KV:email}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" DefaultValue="{OAuth-KV:given_name}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" DefaultValue="{OAuth-KV:display_name}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" DefaultValue="{OAuth-KV:surname}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="jobTitle" DefaultValue="{OAuth-KV:job_title}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_mobilePhone" DefaultValue="{OAuth-KV:mobile_phone}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_organisationName" DefaultValue="{OAuth-KV:organisation_name}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_middleName" DefaultValue="{OAuth-KV:middle_name}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />

            <!-- Optional claims, to be collected from the user -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_mobilePhone" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="jobTitle" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_organisationName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_middleName" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>

TrustFrameworkBase.xml(AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail)
   <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <PersistedClaims>
            <!-- Required claims -->
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" PartnerClaimType="password" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" DefaultValue="unknown" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="passwordPolicies" DefaultValue="DisablePasswordExpiration" />

            <!-- Optional claims. -->
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />

            <!-- Additional claims to persist -->
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="jobTitle" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_mobilePhone" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_middleName" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_organisationName" />
          </PersistedClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" PartnerClaimType="newClaimsPrincipalCreated" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>

SignUp.xml
  <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
    <Endpoints>
      <!--points to refresh token journey when app makes refresh token request-->
      <Endpoint Id="Token" UserJourneyReferenceId="RedeemRefreshToken" />
    </Endpoints>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_middleName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_mobilePhone" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="jobTitle" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_organisationName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>



Here’s a corrected version of your claims mapping string that separates each mapping with a comma and ensures that the logical names are correctly referenced:
firstname=given_name,lastname=surname,emailaddress1=email,middlename=extension_middleName,mobilephone=extension_mobilePhone,jobtitle=job_title,adx_organizationname=extension_organisationName

Tried, it does not seem to work. Upon further investigations I managed to capture my token and see all the data is passed so no issues there.
